# error "Property 'datepicker' does not exist on type 'IAugmentedJQuery' With Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I am using angular JS with Typesscript . But getting error "**Property 'datepicker' does not exist on type 'IAugmentedJQuery'.**" . Please advice how to resolve this error ?

```
 angular.element('input#delegate-from-date').datepicker({
```

thanks in advance !!

Comment: why are you expecting it to be there? it looks like that would be a jquery plugin that's not available by default with angular.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `datepicker.d.ts` file in your project with the following contents:

```
interface IAugmentedJQuery {
    datepicker:any;
}
```

## More

Some tips on migrating :

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html